# How to remove whitespace between list items with inline-block style

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list that I need centered within a div, but also side by side. To do this, I used `text-align: center;` on the div, and `display: inline-block;` on the list items. However, when I do this, some whitespace appears between the list items. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26eg9/)

html

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>buddy</li>
      <li>good</li>
      <li>morning</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 95%;

}

div.wrap {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes because the elements are now treated as words when set to `display: inline-block` so the newline between the elements is treated as a space.

you have a few options, 1 is to remove the newline between the elements: http://jsfiddle.net/26eg9/8/

or you could also set the font size in the parent elemnt to 0 and reset in the list item as such: http://jsfiddle.net/26eg9/3/

Personally I'd prefer the second because it keeps the HTML document looking tidy.

edit: The new lines can be preserved in the first option by putting it inside the list item, only I still think this looks sloppy

Comment: Strange. Why does setting font-size to 0 on parent, then resetting it in list items remove whitespace?

Comment: @Shredder The spacing between inline elements is relative to the font-size. By setting it to 0, you are thus removing it.. Might add that explanation to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks! I'll mark this as accepted because you were the first to have that solution (even though I didn't go with it) it's pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements respect whitespace. Literally remove the whitespace in the markup.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/26eg9/1/) - no whitespace between them

Updated HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
    <li>hello</li><li>buddy</li><li>you</li><li>stink</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are alternatives, such as [**using negative margins (example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/26eg9/6/), or [**setting the parent's `font-size` to 0px (example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/26eg9/5/), then resetting the children. However, the most optimal solution that would be supported across browsers is to remove the whitespace within the markup.

Comment: negative margins sounds like a horrible idea...

Comment: @Don I am merely giving options. I state that it is better to remove the whitespace in the markup, as that will work across browsers.

Comment: No offense intended. Just thought I'd put it out there that as the alternatives go that one sounds horrible

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are coming from the line breaks - HTML interprets new lines as a single whitespace character.

There are a number of ways to get around this - you can add a float to the `li` elements, remove whitespace from the markup, negative margins, etc.  The way that seems most useful in your case is to add `font-size: 0` to the container (I did it to the wrap `div` but you could do it on the `ul` if needed instead) and then set the `font-size` explicitly for the `li`s instead.

```
li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 95%;

}

div.wrap {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[**Here is an updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/26eg9/4/).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Problem and none of the above solutions could fix it. But I found out this works for me:

Instead of this:

```
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>buddy</li>
    <li>good</li>
    <li>morning</li>
</ul>
```

build your html code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> hello </li>
    <li> buddy </li>
    <li> good </li>
    <li> morning </li>
</ul>
```